# Input width to be 100% - 20px

Tags: html, css, yui

I know this isn't possible but I am wondering if there is any other way of achieving the effect.

If you look at the jsfiddle below you will see that the input is 94% of the container and centered, this works OK but what I really want is for the input to have a 10px margin on each side.

http://jsfiddle.net/brendan_rice/4ugxk/13/

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/hRrVv/

Answer (score 1):

Remove **width** from your `.bottom` DIV. Write like this:

```
.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 10px;
    right:10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ugxk/29/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe try something like that http://jsfiddle.net/4ugxk/24/ if it's ok

```
.bottom{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0; right:0;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a wrapping span (or div) around the input element and use that to apply the margin you want. You'd need to remove the default styling from the standard input box (padding, border etc.) and style this wrapping element as you want the input to appear.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4ugxk/43/